# Ruby on Rails -- ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError unexpected if) in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I have the following `.js.coffee` file:

```
$('#search-results').html('<%= j render @articles %>');

$(document).ready () -> 
  dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');

  if (!dialog.showModal) {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
  }

  dialog.showModal();

  dialog.querySelector '.close', addEventListener 'click', () ->
    dialog.close();
```

Why do I get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CoffeeScript you use indentation instead of braces.

Replace

```
if (!dialog.showModal) {
  dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
}
```

With

```
if (!dialog.showModal)
  dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog)
```

I would recommend to go through the [documentation](http://coffeescript.org/)

Comment: Thank you! and excuse ignorance had never used coffee before.